# Determine whether a record is active using an OR Condition on two different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing a tricky problem in that my table has two different columns which decide whether a record is active or not active. (Two different columns because of changes in the same DB again and again not by me of-course.)

The fields are of `bit` type in the database. Can anybody suggest a query which will get the records from table.

ex. select * from product (isActive = 0 or isCancelled =1)

Comment: it depends on how you want to solve the conflicts between the isActive and isCancelled. If they are always opposite then you can check only one of them, otherwise you have to mention in each case what should be considered.

Comment: I don't believe that the column are of Boolean type, since SQL Server doesn't have one of those. Perhaps you meant `bit`...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes you are right,its bit not Boolean.Sorry its my mistake.

Comment: You might also take this opportunity to clean up and phase out one of the columns.  That said, having these two values may be necessary from a legitimate process need.  It's entirely possible that something could be active and cancelled at once (was active, recently set to cancelled, but the cancellation has yet to take place, which would then set active to false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inactive:

```
select * from product where isActive = 0 or isCancelled =1
```

active

```
select * from product where isActive = 1 and isCancelled =0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here's nice way to write this queries

```
select * from product where isActive = 1 and isCancelled = 0 -- Active records
select * from product where not (isActive = 1 and isCancelled = 0) -- Inactive records
```

Comment: is putting "and" between "isActive = 1" and "isCancelled = 0" correct?

Comment: yes, I think that the beauty this code. You take expression to filter active records and then revert it just by putting `not` before

Answer (score 0):

I would select the calculated value:

```
select *, (isActive = 1 and isCancelled = 0) as active
from product
```

or better yet create a view to hide this ugliness:

```
create view complete_product as
select *, (isActive = 1 and isCancelled = 0) as active
from product
```

Comment: is putting "and" between "isActive = 1" and "isCancelled = 0" correct?

Comment: @coge.soft yes, it's correct syntax. each `=` comparison returns a boolean, which is then `AND`ed to return a final boolean